# Partial rendering JSF components

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

dwelling over how to partial render (divs), by including different source files (with panels and components). Depending on menu actions. If  understood the JSF phases correctly, the *View* is rebuilt during the *Render Response*, the last phase. And if I have events and actions, they will be invoked during the *Invoke Application* phase, the phase before.

All I want to do is to set the including xhtml page for a specific menu command via ajax, before the View is re-rendered. But the **ui:include** always get invoked before the menu action. I've tried with richfaces 4 (a4j:param, rich:panel, etc) and standard JSF 2.0 (f:param, h:panelGroup) components, but the the **ui:include** always get invoked before the action.

What should I do to process the menu **action** (to set the including page), before the **ui:include** gets invoked?

PS. This must be the standard patter, instead of including static content. But I find very few examples on this on the net ?!

**Menu.xhtml**

```
<rich:toolbar itemSeparator="line">
...
<rich:dropDownMenu mode="ajax">

    <f:facet name="label">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:outputText value="Menu 1" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </f:facet>
            <rich:menuItem id="newActivityMenu" action="#{navigationBean.menuAction}" render="content" label="New">
                <a4j:param id="newActivityParam" name="includeContentPage" value="/user/Create.xhtml" />
            </rich:menuItem>
...
```

**NavigationBean.Java**

```
    @ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class NavigationBean {

    public String menuAction() {
    String param = JsfUtil.getRequestParameter("includeContentPage");
    this.includedContentPage = param;
    JsfUtil.log(this, "Including Content Page : " +param);

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
    return "";
}

public String getIncludedContentPage() {
    if(includedContentPage == null)
        return "";
    else if(!includedContentPage.endsWith(".xhtml"))
        includedContentPage += ".xhtml";
    JsfUtil.log(this, "Get Content Page : " +includedContentPage);
    return includedContentPage;
    }
```

**layoutClient.xhtml**

```
...
<ui:define name="top">
        <ui:include src="/resources/viewComponents/menuTop.xhtml"/>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">                
        <ui:include src="#{navigationBean.includedContentPage}"/>
    </ui:define>
...
```

**masterLayout.xhtml** (added)

```
...
<h:body>
    <div id="top" >
        <ui:insert name="top">Top Default</ui:insert>
    </div>
    <div id="left">
        <ui:insert name="left">Left Default</ui:insert>
    </div>
         <ui:insert name="content">Content Default</ui:insert>
    </h:body>
..
```

Comment: Actually, the ui:include tag is invoke for other ajax actions (not menu actions) on the page, where I don't explicitly render the "content" div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a template page as well since you are defining *top* and *content* in `layoutClient.xhtml` so I think you are trying to be too general with the `layoutClient.xhtml` page as it appears to be functioning as a template as well. Lets assume your template page is called `template.xhtml`. The standard pattern you eluded to is to make your template page something like this:

#### template.xhtml

```
...
<ui:insert name="top">
    <ui:include src="/resources/viewComponents/menuTop.xhtml"/>
</ui:insert>
...
<ui:insert name="content" />
...
```

This means that all your pages contain the menu at the 'top' (by default, they can override this) and that they must specify their own content, which makes sense.

Now, instead of trying to make a page like `layoutClient.xhtml` that does tricky stuff to determine which content is inserted, create each page seperately like this:

#### page1.xhtml

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
    ...
    <ui:define name="content">
        <p>This is a page that defines some content and also includes my menu that it inherits from template.xhtml</p>
    </ui:define>
    ...
</ui:composition>
```

#### page2.xhtml

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
    ...
    <ui:define name="content">
        <p>This is another page that defines some content and also includes my menu that it inherits from template.xhtml</p>
    </ui:define>
    ...
</ui:composition>
```

Both of these pages inherit your menu and put the content in the appropriate place.

With that kind of configuration, all your `menuAction()` method needs to do is return a link to `page1.xhtml` or `page2.xhtml`. Also, you don't need any complex use of parameters or manual calls to `renderResponse()` or `a4j:param` tags!

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I do have a template file called masterLayout.xhtml (above), but forgot to include it. Maybe I'll try try to hard to load dynamically the content into the same page. But with your solution, I'll guess that the whole page has to be refreshed ?

Comment: Yes that's right. It's a small price to pay for cleaner and more easily maintainable code (IMO). Also, the back button will work as expected if you always use AJAX within the page. If you use AJAX to navigate, it will not be recorded in page history and therefore pressing back would take the user to the last page before `layoutClient.xhtml`.